# "No suitable constructor was found for entity type" when adding migrations for entities with value objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, value-objects

I have a Supplier entity

**Supplier Entity**

```
public class Supplier : BaseEntity
{
    public string? AccountCode { get; set; }
    public string? CompanyName { get; set; }
    public List<Address>? Addresses { get; set; } = new();
    public List<Person>? People { get; set; } = new();
    public List<SocialMediaAccount>? SocialMediaAccounts { get; set; } = new();
    public Media? Logo { get; set; }
    public Media? CoverPicture { get; set; }
}
```

Address, Person and SocialMediaAccount are value objects as below; I am giving code for Address only since this is where the error occurs.

**Address ValueObject**

```
public class Address : ValueObject
{
    public string? AddressLabel { get; init; }
    public string? BuildingName { get; init; }
    public string? UnitNumber { get; set; }
    public string? StreetAddress1 { get; init; }
    public string? StreetAddress2 { get; init; }
    public string? MinorMunicipality { get; init; } 
    public string? MajorMunicipality { get; init; } 
    public string? County { get; init; }
    public string? PostCode { get; init; }
    public Country? Country { get; init; }

    public Address(string? addressLabel, string? buildingName, string? unitNumber, string? streetAddress1, string? streetAddress2, string? minorMunicipality, string? majorMunicipality, string? county, string? postCode, Country? country)
    {
        AddressLabel= addressLabel;
        BuildingName = buildingName;
        UnitNumber = unitNumber;
        StreetAddress1 = streetAddress1;
        StreetAddress2 = streetAddress2;
        MinorMunicipality = minorMunicipality;
        MajorMunicipality = majorMunicipality;
        County = county;
        PostCode = postCode;
        Country = country;
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object?> GetEqualityComponents()
    {
        yield return AddressLabel;
        yield return BuildingName;
        yield return UnitNumber;
        yield return StreetAddress1;
        yield return StreetAddress2;
        yield return MinorMunicipality;
        yield return MajorMunicipality;
        yield return County;
        yield return PostCode;
        yield return Country;
    }
}
```

Within the Address value object, **Country ValueObject** is also a value object

```
public class Country : ValueObject
{
    public string? Name { get; init; }
    public string? Alpha3Code { get; init; }
    public string? EmojiFlag { get; init; }

    public Country(string? name, string? alpha3Code, string? emojiFlag)
    {
        Name = name;
        Alpha3Code = alpha3Code;
        EmojiFlag = emojiFlag;
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object?> GetEqualityComponents()
    {
        yield return Name;
        yield return Alpha3Code;
        yield return EmojiFlag;
    }
}
```

My **SupplierConfiguration** class is as follows;

```
public class SupplierConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Supplier>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Supplier> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(t => t.AccountCode)
            .HasMaxLength(32);

        builder.Property(t => t.CompanyName)
            .HasMaxLength(512)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.OwnsMany(p => p.Addresses, addressNavigationBuilder =>
        {
            addressNavigationBuilder.Property(t => t.AddressLabel).HasMaxLength(64).IsRequired();
            addressNavigationBuilder.Property(t => t.BuildingName).HasMaxLength(64);
            addressNavigationBuilder.Property(t => t.UnitNumber).HasMaxLength(32);
            addressNavigationBuilder.Property(t => t.StreetAddress1).HasMaxLength(256);
            addressNavigationBuilder.Property(t => t.StreetAddress2).HasMaxLength(256);
            addressNavigationBuilder.Property(t => t.MinorMunicipality).HasMaxLength(128);
            addressNavigationBuilder.Property(t => t.MajorMunicipality).HasMaxLength(128);
            addressNavigationBuilder.Property(t => t.County).HasMaxLength(128);
            addressNavigationBuilder.Property(t => t.PostCode).HasMaxLength(32);


            addressNavigationBuilder.OwnsOne(t => t.Country, countryNavigationBuilder =>
            {
                countryNavigationBuilder.Property(c => c.Name).HasMaxLength(64);
                countryNavigationBuilder.Property(c => c.Alpha3Code).HasMaxLength(3);
                countryNavigationBuilder.Property(c => c.EmojiFlag).HasMaxLength(50);
            });

        });

         builder.OwnsMany(p => p.SocialMediaAccounts, socialMediaAccountNavigationBuilder =>
            {
                socialMediaAccountNavigationBuilder.Property(t => t.Handle).HasMaxLength(maxLength: 128);
                socialMediaAccountNavigationBuilder.Property(t => t.FullURL).HasMaxLength(2048).IsRequired();
            });

        builder.OwnsMany(c => c.People, personNavigationBuilder =>
            {
                personNavigationBuilder.Property(t => t.Prefix).HasMaxLength(12);

                personNavigationBuilder.Property(t => t.FirstName).HasMaxLength(128).IsRequired();

                personNavigationBuilder.Property(t => t.MiddleName).HasMaxLength(128);

                personNavigationBuilder.Property(t => t.LastName).HasMaxLength(128).IsRequired();

                personNavigationBuilder.Property(t => t.JobTitle).HasMaxLength(128);

                personNavigationBuilder.Property(t => t.Notes).HasMaxLength(512);

                personNavigationBuilder.OwnsOne(p => p.ProfilePicture);

                personNavigationBuilder.OwnsMany(p => p.EmailAddresses, emailNavigationBuilder =>
                {
                    emailNavigationBuilder.Property(e => e.Email).HasMaxLength(128).IsRequired();
                    emailNavigationBuilder.Property(e => e.Label).HasMaxLength(128);
                });

                personNavigationBuilder.OwnsMany(p => p.SocialMediaAccounts, socialMediaAccountNavigationBuilder =>
                {
                    socialMediaAccountNavigationBuilder.Property(t => t.Handle).HasMaxLength(maxLength: 128);
                    socialMediaAccountNavigationBuilder.Property(t => t.FullURL).HasMaxLength(2048).IsRequired();
                });

                builder.OwnsOne(p => p.Logo, logoNavigationBuilder =>
                {
                    logoNavigationBuilder.Property(l => l.Label).HasMaxLength(128).IsRequired();
                    logoNavigationBuilder.Property(l => l.MediaFor).HasMaxLength(64).IsRequired();
                    logoNavigationBuilder.Property(l => l.MediaFor).HasMaxLength(512).IsRequired();
                });

                builder.OwnsOne(p => p.CoverPicture, coverPictureNavigationBuilder =>
                {
                    coverPictureNavigationBuilder.Property(l => l.Label).HasMaxLength(128).IsRequired();
                    coverPictureNavigationBuilder.Property(l => l.MediaFor).HasMaxLength(64).IsRequired();
                    coverPictureNavigationBuilder.Property(l => l.MediaFor).HasMaxLength(512).IsRequired();
                });

            });
    }
}
```

When I try to run migration to create my initial database, I get the following error
*No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'Supplier.Addresses#Address'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type:
Cannot bind 'country' in 'Supplier.Addresses#Address(string addressLabel, string buildingName, string unitNumber, string streetAddress1, string streetAddress2, string minorMunicipality, string majorMunicipality, string county, string postCode, Country country)'
Note that only mapped properties can be bound to constructor parameters. Navigations to related entities, including references to owned types, cannot be bound.*

I would be grateful if someone help me solve this.